# Autoincremented number within group of entities

Tags: postgresql

I'm not a big expert in SQL, so I need help from community.

I have the following simplified tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "Keyspace" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "tenantId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Keyspace_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "Project" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "tenantId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "keyspaceId" INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Project_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "Entry" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "tenantId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "projectId" INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Entry_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "KeyspaceEntry" (
    "keyspaceId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "entryId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "number" INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

One `Entry` can be only in one `Keyspace`. This is enforced by `Entry`->`Project`->`Keyspace` reference.

One `Keyspace` will have many `Entries`.

The important field is `KeyspaceEntry.number`. This is the autoincremented number for each Entry within the same Keyspace.

Example:

- "Keyspace #1" have 3 entries with numbers `1`,`2`,`3`
- "Keyspace #2" have 2 entries with numbers `1`,`2`
- When you create a new entry in "Project X" that references "Keyspace #1", then KeyspaceEntry should be created with `number=4`.

I need to implement atomic insert for Entry and KeyspaceEntry with incremented `number` within the same transaction.

Note: It may look unnecessary to have the KeyspaceEntry table because you can simply add `number` property to the Entry, but this is a simplified model. I want to have a history of all Keyspace-Entry relationships for the case when an entry is moved to a different project under a different keyspace.

Another option can be creating a historical table but keeping the actual `Entry.number` property. It may be better for querying Entries (it will be used for selecting individual Entries by KeyspaceID+EntryNumber), I may consider this later as well. Please share if you have opinion on this design change.

I'm using PostgreSQL 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parent( parent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE child( parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES parent(parent_id), number INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1),(2);
```

In two different terminals, concurrently:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1 FROM parent WHERE parent_id=1 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO child SELECT 1, (SELECT coalesce(min(number)+1,1) FROM child WHERE parent_id=1);
-- switch to other terminal
COMMIT;
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM child;
 parent_id | number
-----------+--------
         1 |      1
         1 |      2
```

SELECT FOR UPDATE will lock the row in parent table for the length of the transaction, which forces other SELECTs FOR UPDATE to wait. When the first transaction (insert with number 1) is committed, the the second one takes the lock, it can see the row with number=1 that was just inserted, and inserts with number=2.

In these types of queries you have to lock the row in the parent table (keyspace), not the child table (keyspaceEntry). The main reason is you need to have the incremented number first before doing the insert, and you need the lock to increment the number, so the order has to be: lock, increment, insert. You can't lock a row that hasn't been inserted yet, and the inserted row is not visible to concurrent transactions until commit.

Locking the row in the parent table is unambiguous, due to the foreign key you know it exists and it is unique. This row is also visible to all concurrent transactions that try to insert with the same parent_id (keyspaceid).

An index on (parent_id,number) will speed up max() and avoid sorting if you want to select with ORDER BY parent_id, number which I presume is one of the goals of the operation.

Transactions should be kept short as holding the lock on parent prevents inserting into child table concurrently.

To make sure the id is always generated, this should go in a BEFORE INSERT trigger on child.

I used something like this on a forum. Pagination used LIMIT and OFFSET, which was slow. I replaced it with a "post number in topic" column allowing to find the desired posts directly.

Deleting rows will make holes in the sequence.

Inserting a new row after the highest number one was deleted will reuse the number. For primary keys this is undesirable, and it's a good thing sequences don't have this behavior. If you don't want reuse of number, then you have to put a counter in the parent table and increment it every time you insert a child. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent( parent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, children_counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );
CREATE TABLE child( parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES parent(parent_id), number INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1),(2);

WITH n AS (UPDATE parent SET children_counter=children_counter+1 WHERE parent_id=1 RETURNING children_counter)
INSERT INTO child SELECT 1, (SELECT children_counter FROM n);
```

With this one, there's no need to SELECT FOR UPDATE, because the UPDATE on parent table takes the lock. So if you just want to insert one row into the child table, you don't need to explicitly BEGIN the transaction, it does everything in one query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reusing the numbers is not desirable, but deleting an entry will not be possible. In my case, I'll use soft deletes. One question: should I `select for update` the `Keyspace` table with the given `keyspaceId` or `KeyspaceEntry` with the given `keyspaceId`? My understanding is that locking Keyspace will use fewer resources (locking only one row), and a similar operation will be dependent on Keyspace with the same ID, so it will wait until the first transaction commits, and there will be no race conditions on KeyspaceEntry. Just to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes. You can't lock the row in KeyspaceEntry because you haven't inserted it yet... You could lock the previous row, but if there are no entries for this keyspace yet and you're inserting the first, then there's no row to lock. It's much better to lock the row in the parent table (Keyspace), because you know it exists (due to the foreign key), there's only one row with this keyspaceid, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I have added an example with non-reusable keys, using a counter in the parent table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. This solution is interesting. With a counter in the parent/keyspacee table I can use it directly on the entry row. I don't need `KeyspaceEntry` table in this case. And in order to have the history of the Keyspace+Entry relationships, I can create a simple history table with no FKs, which can be populated automatically with the DB trigger. Everything will be much simpler. This history table is needed only to resolve obsolete URLs when the keyspace URL alias is changed, or the keyspace is changed for the project with existing entries.

Comment: I think it still makes sense to start a transaction and lock at least Project to avoid a change of `Project.keyspace` in the middle. When `Project.keyspace` is changing I'll need to regenerate new numbers for all Project's Entries.

Comment: Right, it makes sense. To regenerate numbers you can use window function row_number() with the order of your choosing so the numbers end up in the order you want.